If someone has a published work but hasn't done anything with it for ten years, can I use the title without risk of trademark?
There is a comic book, the most recent related item published in May 2014. The author hasn't worked with the item or associated objects since a 2015 intellectual property infringement over the title but still sells as of 2024. In fall 2024, can I use the title?

How do you know the author is not using it commercially?  Creature Academy: The Legacy seems to be currently available for Kindle.

Sorry; I meant that it hasn't been trademarked in ten years

I also only want to use the "Creature Academy" part

Please ask your publisher's lawyer, not Randos on the internet.

What do you mean by "trademarked in ten years"? You don't have to renew registration of a trademark.

Okay Barmar. And okay Trish, I'll do that

Offering a product for sale is sufficient to keep a trademark alive. So, no.

or rather more on point, it could be formulated: To keep a trademark alive, you need to use it in commerce. Offering a product for sale is a quintessential style of use in commerce.
